# Any way to tell what text message another message is in response to?

Tags: sms, response, twilio

Are there any texting services out there (like Twilio) with APIs that allow you to see what message another message is in response to? For example: I want to tell whether message 3 is in response to 1 or 2.

1. A->B: Do you like ice cream?
2. A->B: Do you like pizza?
3. B->A: Yes.

I'm guessing that there's just no threadedness to text messages, and this is impossible. But might as well have a canonical answer out there.... Reasons for this belief:

1. When you send emails to a phone number at txt.att.net, it uses a different number each time.
2. The texting services that I've looked at don't offer the feature
3. The phone UIs I've used all present it as a flat message list rather than a threaded list

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native support for this type of functionality in SMS.  Message threading for SMS is inferred on the client side from context.  When I send a text to person 1, if I receive a reply from person 1 within a given time-frame, I can assume that it was part of the same "conversation". (I actually implemented something like this for a chat client that I was working on)

I have also seen where the original message is included with the response, and the client can group the messages accordingly (take a look at gmail), but this could be messy if your clients were not the same.

Just a few thoughts.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted confirmation :)